# How to prevent memory limit fatal error when blurring in image in php?

Tags: php, image, memory

I have written an algorithm which gaussian blurs an image by a customizable radius just like this one: [FastBlur.js](http://www.quasimondo.com/BoxBlurForCanvas/FastBlur.js) (function boxBlurCanvasRGB) but only ported to php.

When I pick an image with 512x384 pixels, the function works wonderfully. Bigger images cause a fatal php error (memory exceeds). But the goal is to use any image dimension and give a warning before a fatal error occurs.

Something like:

```
if ($memory_needed_for_this > $available_memory_at_all) { return false; }
```

Is it possible the calculate the amount of memory needed for a process or check how much memory is currently being used lets say within a for each loop?

Thanks

Comment: "Any dimension" will not work. You will always be memory bound. You can change the `memory_limit` php uses and reduce memory usage in your script by unsetting no longer used variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do some testing and sample the usage of memory - if it's consistent with the growth of image size, you can easily figure the max size.

Comment: well half the dimensions are not equal with half of memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE) /:

Comment: just to be sure - are you doing like this: area = w*h; memory_usage = memory_get_peak_usage(true) - then correlation = memory_usage / area; further use correlation * new_area to estimate potential usage of memory, based on the dimensions of the image. also, you should see if perhaps parabolic function is better representing the correlation between size & memory - I would suggest using give win or spss to do the statistical analysis, once you have gathered data.

Comment: for example, processing an 128x96 image debugs the following memory usage (peak): 26214400. this memory divided by 128x96 = 2133,33333333 (=correlation). doing correlation * 256*192 (which is 104857600) IS NOT equal with the actual debugged memory peak called with 256x192 which is 65011712

Comment: 128x96 - 2133.33, 256x192 - 1322.67 -- you should have at least 5 different aspect ratios, and run each test at least 5 times. that then plot area size and ratio in excel and add  trendline. see which fits best. if there is no trend, then answer to you original question is that you cannot check for memory. instead you can try to catch the memory leak error and handle it.

Comment: ive tried only 3 times yet. i will try it with 5 and check for a trend. thanks so far!

Comment: finally, you might want to consider using Imagick that has native gaussianBlurImage implementation. http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.gaussianblurimage.php

Answer (score 0):

`memory_get_usage`

Returns the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php

Comment: i know, memory peak should be even more precise but how to use that to prevent a fatal error?